# Iterating through JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I parse the response from a web service into a `JSONObject`, which when logged, looks as follows:

```
{"Preferences":"{Pref1=Apple, Pref2=Pear}"}
```

I understand how to ask for the **Preferences** tag e.g. `jsonObject.get("Preferences")`. However, I do not understand what object I am getting back nor how to iterate over it. How can I iterate over the object returned by `jsonObject.get("Preferences")`?

Comment: in this particular case you do not get a json object, but a string

Comment: @blackbelt is right.  Maybe the service should be returning {"Preferences":{"Pref1" : "Apple", "Pref2":"Pear"}}.

Answer (score 12):

the object returned by preferences is a `String`. If you want to iterate through the childs of Preferences you may want to change the structure, to for example:

```
{"Preferences":{"Pref1":"Apple", "Pref2":"Pear"}}
```

and parse it like this:

```
JSONObject inputJSON = new JSONObject("{\"Preferences\":{\"Pref1\":\"Apple\", \"Pref2\":\"Pear\"}}");
JSONObject preferencesJSON = inputJSON.getJSONObject("Preferences");
Iterator<String> keysIterator = preferencesJSON.keys();
while (keysIterator.hasNext()) 
{
        String keyStr = (String)keysIterator.next();
        String valueStr = preferencesJSON.getString(keyStr);
}
```

alternatively, if you want to keep your structure, you can parse the returned string by the Preferences object like this:

```
JSONObject inputJSON = new JSONObject("{\"Preferences\":\"{Pref1=Apple, Pref2=Pear}\"}");
String preferencesStr = inputJSON.getString("Preferences");
JSONObject preferencesJSON = new JSONObject(preferencesStr);
Iterator<String> keysIterator = preferencesJSON.keys();
while (keysIterator.hasNext()) 
{
        String keyStr = (String)keysIterator.next();
        String valueStr = preferencesJSON.getString(keyStr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't iterate through above JsonObject, but if it were like this

```
["Preferences":{"Pref1":"Juan", "Pref2":"JuanK"}]
```

you could have done like

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(dataInStringForm);

for (int i=0;i< array.length(); i++)
{
   JSONObject json = array.getJsonObject(i);

   System.out.println(json.getString("Pref1"));
   System.out.println(json.getString("Pref2"));
}
```

Comment: This would probably (not tested) throw a `JSONException` at `json.getString("Pref1")` and `json.getString("Pref2")`since Pref1 and Pref2 are not mapped.

Comment: I know every string is enclosed in quotes "" when the json data is returned from internet, so this code won't give any exception as long as the JsonData is properly formated.

Comment: Now it will throw a `JSONException` because you used `=`instead of `:` ;)

Comment: You probably want:`["Preferences":{"Pref1":"Juan", "Pref2":"JuanK"}]`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse values from `JSONObject` and can use `getJSONObject(i)` in a loop if it's a `JSONArray`. In your case you should make your preferences a `JSONArray`
`[{"Pref1":"Juan"},{"Pref2":"JuanK"}]` so you can get it via `getJSONArray()` and then parse it better in a loop via  `getJSONObject(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String key = iter.next();
            try {
                Object value = json.get(key);
            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }
        }
```

If it is array then

```
JSONArray key= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("yourKey");
        Iterator<String> iterator = key.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
```